# Am i doing SQL Statements in my models classes correctly?

Tags: php, sql, model-view-controller

I would like to seek advice for a design concept. I created my own MVC framework.

For the model classes, these are the classes that main retrieve data from my database.

In a class for example (`User`), I have the following methods

- `get_user`.
- `get_recent_activity`.

Basically for example in `get_recent_activity` method, I will have a sql statement that do the execution to get the data.

I am thinking of another design, that is extending each of the classes (e.g. `User`) with a `Sql` class. In this class, it will contain all sql necessary queries.

For example an insert query using the sql class will be like

```
$sqlqueries->select("table","user=john&email=john@hotmail.com");
```

Will this be a better design? For maintenance or so? I am worrying about the performance issue as now to get data from the methods, first the select method from the sql classes need to process the variables first.

Comment: why don't you use ORM ? For example https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a personal account of how I approach designing my own framework classes when working with a database.

Typically, when designing an MVC framework, I lay out two core concepts for developing the classes:

- a single database class that manages various aspects such as query building, row count return, insert ID, etc.
- an interface data class to ensure that each class remains consistent (for example, each class must have all four [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations)

**Database class**

My database class usually looks something like the following. You will notice towards the bottom that there are mutator functions like you have specified. These are specifically designed only to **set** and **get** data from the class itself. There is minor validation (`if(is_resource(...))` in get_connection), though I have heard that this sort of code should be in the Model level.

```
    public $error;

    private $location = '';
    private $username = '';
    private $password = '';
    private $database = '';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $connection = mysql_connect($this->location,$this->username,$this->password);

        $this->set_connection($connection);

        $db_select = mysql_select_db($this->database,$this->get_connection());
    }

    public function query()
    {
        $query = mysql_query($this->query,$this->connection);

        $this->set_insert_id(mysql_insert_id($this->connection));

        switch(substr(strtolower($this->query),0,6))
        {
            case 'select':
                $this->set_row_count(mysql_num_rows($query));

                $row_count = $this->get_row_count();

                if($row_count == 0)
                {
                    $this->set_results(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                    {
                        $results = $this->get_results();
                        $results[] = $result;
                        $this->set_results($results);
                    }
                }
            break;
            case 'insert':
            case 'update':
            case 'delete':
            case 'replace':
            default:
                $this->set_results(($query === true));
            break;
        }
    }

    public function get_query()
    {
        return $this->query;
    }

    public function set_query($query)
    {
        $this->query = $query;
    }

    public function get_insert_id()
    {
        return $this->insert_id;
    }

    public function set_insert_id($insert_id)
    {
        if(is_numeric($insert_id))
        {
            $this->insert_id = $insert_id;
        }
    }

    public function get_results()
    {
        return $this->results;
    }

    public function set_results($results)
    {
        $this->results = $results;
    }

    public function get_row_count()
    {
        return $this->row_count;
    }

    public function set_row_count($row_count)
    {
        if(is_numeric($row_count))
        {
            $this->row_count = $row_count;
        }
    }

    public function get_connection()
    {
        return $this->connection;
    }

    public function set_connection($connection)
    {
        if(is_resource($connection))
        {
            $this->connection = $connection;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->connection = false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Data class**

The interface data class is simply a guideline for other classes, so its very straightforward. When doing this approach, it's easy to manipulate with your data.

```
<?php
interface Data {
    public function create();
    public function read();
    public function update();
    public function delete();
}
?>
```

**An example class**

Here is an example class that I would typically use with the previous stated classes that manipulates the Database and Data classes. When using a typical CRUD operation, I do a call to the Database class, set the query, query the database, then return the results. That's as simple as it can get, and any other further requirements can be appended into each function.

```
<?php
require_once('classes/class.Data.php');
require_once('classes/class.Database.php');
class Settings implements Data {
    private $profile_id;
    private $settings = array();

    public function create()
    {
        $settings_instance = new Database;
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO settings (' . implode(',',array_keys($this->settings)) . ') VALUES ("' . implode('","',array_values($this->settings)) . '");';
        $settings_instance->set_query($sql);
        $settings_instance->query();
        return $settings_instance->get_results();
    }

    public function read()
    {
        $settings_instance = new Database;
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM settings WHERE profile_id = "' . $this->profile_id . '"';
        $settings_instance->set_query($sql);
        $settings_instance->query();

        $settings_results = $settings_instance->get_results();

        if($settings_results)
        {
            $this->set_settings($settings_results[0]);
        }
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $keys = array_keys($this->settings);
        $values = array_values($this->settings);
        $settings_instance = new Database;
        $sql = 'UPDATE settings SET ';
        foreach($keys as $index => $key)
        {
            if($keys[$index] == "profile_id")
                continue;
            $sql .= $keys[$index] . ' = "' . $values[$index] . '", ';
        }
        $sql = rtrim($sql,', ');
        $sql .= ' WHERE profile_id = "' . $this->profile_id . '"';
        $settings_instance->set_query($sql);
        $settings_instance->query();
        return $settings_instance->get_results();
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        $settings_instance = new Database;
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM settings WHERE profile_id = "' . $this->profile_id . '"';
        $settings_instance->set_query($sql);
        $settings_instance->query();
        return $settings_instance->get_results();
    }

    public function get_profile_id()
    {
        return $this->profile_id;
    }

    public function set_profile_id($profile_id)
    {
        if(is_numeric($profile_id))
        {
            $this->profile_id = $profile_id;
        }
    }

    public function get_setting($index)
    {
        if(isset($this->settings[$index]))
        {
            return $this->settings[$index];
        }
    }

    public function set_setting($index,$new_value)
    {
        if(isset($this->settings[$index]))
        {
            $this->settings[$index] = $new_value;
        }
    }

    public function get_settings()
    {
        return $this->settings;
    }

    public function set_settings($settings)
    {
        if(is_array($settings))
        {
            $this->settings = $settings;
        }
    }

    public function get_setting_types()
    {
        return $this->setting_types;
    }

    public function set_setting_types($setting_types)
    {
        if(is_array($setting_types))
        {
            $this->setting_types = $setting_types;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Some example code**

Here is some example Model code to go along with this approach. I find this to be quite readable. It will create a new settings row in the database with the profile_id = 1.

```
require_once('class.Settings.php');
$Settings = new Settings;
$Settings->set_profile_id(1);
$Settings->create();
```

Comment: thank you ..that helps. I assume that your data class is similar to the sql class that i mentioned right?

Answer (score 0):

The Sql class that you mentioned looks like a Repository pattern to me. Indeed has maintenance benefits but also helps with unit testing, a better separation of concers and a cleaner code.

Comment: how about performance? for example.

sqlqueries->select("table","user=john&email=john@hotmail.com");

I do need to process"user=john&email=john@hotmail.com" first, explode the variables and format it nicely into sql format.. will that cause some performance issues as there is extra code.